# R Create new column with flag

Tags: r

Using R I want to create a new column that flags data based on the frequency of a variable. Currently, I have code that removes these points instead of adding a flag column. I need to flag data that has less than 7200 records that are also dentoed as `y` or `n` by another column.

My current code that removes these reocords as such:

```
# Read in csv file
data = read.csv(infile)

# Create subset with only records marked 'y'
data_y = subset(data,data$yn!= 'n')

# Count the number of records per day, using table function
valid = table(data_y$DATE)

# Remove the records with less than 7200 records, and also marked 'y' from subset function
df_cut = data_w[data_w$DATE_STAMP %in% names(valid)[valid>=7200],]

# Save new cvs
write.csv(df_cut,outpath)
```

I'm assuming I won't want to use subset as this tells R to ignore those records but not sure where to start.

Comment: As a side note, the main feature of `subset` is not having to qualify columns with `parent_object$`; e.g.`subset(data, yn !=  'n')`.

Comment: Something like `data$flag = ave(data[, 1], data$DATE, data$yn, FUN = function(x) length(x) < 7200)`. This will add a column called `"flag"` that is TRUE when there are less than 7200 rows for each DATE/YN combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're asking for but...

```
tmp <- data.frame(table(data$DATE)) 
tmp <- tmp[tmp$Freq < 7200,]

data$flagColumn <- "n"

for(i in 1:nrow(tmp)){
   data$flagColumn[data$DATE == tmp$Freq[i]] <- "y"
}
```

If you need to add multiple conditions you can add them with '&'

```
 data$flagColumn[(data$DATE == tmp$Freq[i]]) & data$someOtherCol =="n"] <- "y"
```